# Why do I get the "cannot serialize error" when I try to migrate my model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, model

Well I'm very new to django, so I got lost easily. I'm trying to build my model, using my sql model as reference (I suppose that's the way people do).
I solved most errors, but the last one is killing me and I don't find help on the net.
This is my code :

```
from phone_field import PhoneField

# Create your models here.


class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default="3")
    max_score = models.IntegerField(default="100")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="inactive")


class Credit(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=3)


class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="chinese")


class Token(models.Model):
    token_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)


class Level(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(default="1")


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phone_number = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
    date = models.DateTimeField('date of event')
    members = models.IntegerField()
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default="chinese")
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default="1")


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    token_id = models.ForeignKey(Token, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=Event.language)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=Event.level)
    players_number = models.IntegerField(default="3")
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    activation_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active_room = models.ForeignKey(Room, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    total_score = models.IntegerField(default="0")


class ScoreTable(models.Model):
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_number = models.ForeignKey(Room, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default="0")
    time = models.DateTimeField('time of scoring', auto_now_add=True)


class BestScore(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    total_score = models.IntegerField(default="0")
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I try to migrate my model I got this error :

```
(mysite) MBPdeAlexandre:mysite nivren$ python manage.py makemigrations manager
Migrations for 'manager':
  manager/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model BestScore
    - Create model Credit
    - Create model Event
    - Create model Language
    - Create model Level
    - Create model Room
    - Create model Token
    - Create model Team
    - Create model ScoreTable
    - Add field language to event
    - Add field level to event
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 182, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 219, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 141, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 99, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 51, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 271, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 37, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 199, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 86, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/Users/nivren/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 336, in serializer_factory
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x10a7d5310>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

OK, I have my foreign key "language" that is referenced in "team" and "event", and "event" is also referenced in "team". This looked clear in my mind : an event can be set with a language, but one of the teams participating to this event can overload the language choice, always choosing from the language list. Is there something I didn't understood in django model philosophy?
Thanks for your help, in the mean time I'll continue looking for answers :)

Comment: Why are you trying to seralise the regex validator into your model? the validator is just that, it should validate your data but it shouldnt be part of your model. There is a link at the bottom of your start trace that talks about serialisation and what you can and cannot serialize.

Comment: I changed the function used to store. You were right. But still got the same mistake after. It doesn't like my foreign keys, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your models, specifically `PhoneModel`.
You are using wrong to implement validator.
Refer to this link to understand validator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#writing-validators

Your code should look like

```
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be: '+999999999'. Max 15 digits.")
class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
```

also you can implement it another way like this:

```
class ReceiverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone_number = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', 
                                error_message = ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."))
```

Correct me it doesn't work

Comment: same here, I changed the phone part using another package that I downloaded. But it seems not to like my foreign keys. I updated the post.

Comment: Please first delete ***migration*** folder, then try to run cmd ```python manage.py makemugrations```

Comment: same. I tried it all and it goes to the same mistake. Thank you for the advice that I didn't know, might help one day. I commented the foreign keys and it worked. Means there is something in my foreign keys that django doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found my problem. I was saying that if the language for the "team" is deleted, then it should use the language value from the "event". Django doesn't like it. I don't know why, but it causes problem. Now that I put a real default value, it accepts my migration. If someone can explain to me in comment it would be great :)